# How to read product options values in cart on catalog_product_load_after event

Tags: event-observer, custom-options

I need to read the product options values just after a product is added to cart. I then have an observer on catalog_product_load_after (I use this event as trigger as my method is also called for product page which run the same event)

I tried to do :

```
$_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$options = $_product->getOptions();
```

But it does not work…

Thank you for your help,

Alex

Comment: Do you want all options on the product or the specific options on the quote item?

Comment: I would like to access the options values entered by the customer on the product page...

Comment: Then you need access to the quote_item, not the product. The product is a product, there are no information about customer, choosen options, etc. in it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I think that when the `catalog_product_load_after` is called when a product is added to cart, the quote item is not yet defined. Therefore it seems not to be possible to access the item options values…

Indeed, if a `$urlParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();` is done on the observer, we can see that the options values are posted in the URL… So not stored yet in the item...

I then changed the triggering event of my method on `checkout_cart_product_add_after`